# Reloading ViewPager within ViewPager after Data Set Changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, android-viewpager, android-adapter

The main activity of my Android application features a ViewPager (V4) that has disabled swiping capabilities. Therefore, the user navigates the ViewPager using tabs. In one of these tabs (so within a Fragment of the first ViewPager), there is another ViewPager. However, in another view of the first ViewPager, I update the contents / data set of the internal ViewPager. Whatever I do, this internal ViewPager will not update its Views (which I know it receives by counting the number of children within it). How do I refresh the internal ViewPager when it is switched to? I have tried the code below within the Fragment holding the internal ViewPager:

```
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        if(isVisibleToUser){
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.e("DATA CHANGE", "Count: " + adapter.getCount());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            mViewPager.invalidate();
        }
    }
```